# Relation between cmd_vel and odometry twist data?

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some short questions please if anyone can answer these questions.

Q1: What will be the unit of angle when we use

```
angle = tf::getYaw(odom.pose.pose.orientation);
```

Q2: What should be the unit of linear and angular velocity when setting cmd_vel of diffrential drive robots?  i.e.

```
cmdvel_.linear.x = vt;  // (m/s)    
cmdvel_.angular.z = w;  // (rad/s) is it ok?
```

Q3: What is the unit of `Odometry.twist.twist.angular.z`?

Q4: If I want to find the previous velocity vector from Odometry data. Am I doing right? I want to find velocity vector in Odom frame?

```
linearV = (odom.twist.twist.linear.x);
angularV = (odom_globalVal.twist.twist.angular.z);

Vx = linearV * cos(angularV);  // wrong::its not an angle its angular velocity

Vy = linearV * sin(angularV);  // wrong
```

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44624/relation-between-cmd_vel-and-odometry-twist-data?/) by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zuhair95](https://answers.ros.org/users/87984/zuhair95/) on 2022-08-15**:
I hope you got to solve your issue!
Please, to select the correct Gmapping odometry model noise (srr, srt, str, stt):
Is it correct to calculate the RMSE between /cmd_vel/linear/x and /odom/twist/twsit/linear/x for translation and RMSE between /cmd_vel/angular/z and /odom/twist/twist/angular/z for rotation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Great references (and hopefully they clarify your questions too) are on the wiki and the REPs, e.g. [distances are in meters, angles are in radians](http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry/CoordinateFrameConventions)  or more broadly, [SI or SI-derived units](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) are to be used (by everyone).

Remember that the [twist message](http://ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) "expresses velocity in free space broken into it's linear and angular parts." So angular.z is the angular velocity (not an angle).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on 2012-09-26**:
Thanks, It helps a lot. In  my implementation I want to find the previous velocity vector of differential drive robot. Is there any possibility that I can find it from Odometry data.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-26**:
Yes. The Odometry message contains the current Twist (and its covariance) at the time of that measurement.

**Comment by [Zuhair95](https://answers.ros.org/users/87984/zuhair95/) on 2022-08-15**:
Thanks for the information!
Please, to select the correct Gmapping odometry model noise (srr, srt, str, stt):
Is it correct to calculate the RMSE between /cmd_vel/linear/x and /odom/twist/twsit/linear/x for translation and RMSE between /cmd_vel/angular/z and /odom/twist/twist/angular/z for rotation ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) that defines the standard units that should be used in ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1